# Laravel displays a blank screen and shows two public redirections

Tags: php, laravel

I am try to run a cloned web application in the localhost and all I am getting is a blank screen and two public file redirections on the browser. how can i solve it: make it display the data in the project? please help

http://localhost:7070/adept_writers/public/public

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjOFp.png)

Comment: Can you tell us more about it? How do you run it? Have you checked your php error logs? Please add any additional info to your question

Comment: @Hoargarth I am new to laravel. I am running it through localhost and I have also checked error log from apache and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache, check the .htaccess file.

probably you can find the redirect in this file.

you should make changes in the conf file to open your project from the public folder.

like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/your-project-folder/public/"
    ServerName testphplikepro.test
    ServerAlias *.testphplikepro.test
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/your-project-folder/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: still not working and the browser is still showing two public

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/adept_writers/public/"
    ServerName adept.test
    ServerAlias *.testphplikepro.test
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/adept_writers/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: have you replaced lines: 2,3,4,5 ? why I can see  testphplikepro.test in your codes???

Comment: sorry let me edit then try if it will work. <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/adept_writers/public/"
    ServerName adept.test
    ServerAlias *.adept.test
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/adept_writers/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some change............
Create one more .htaccess file in Root and add this code in there

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]
```

Secondly...Don't Forget to clear browser cache.

Third: The .htaccess file in Public Folder should also  contain the same code as given above.